# Injecting Javascript inside IOS webview depending on scenario like in Android

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, ios10, wkwebview

I am currently trying to port an existing Android application that we have to an IOS app. The issue here is that a large portion of our Android app was made using a lot of webviews with custom Javascript code called from Android.

If anyone is not familiar with it, the code for android would go something like this:

```
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebInterface(this), "Android");
// more settings or whatever
mWebView.loadUrl("yourUrl.html.whatever");
```

Then the interface to the Javascript code reads like this:

```
public class WebInterface {
    Context mContext;
    public WebInterface(Context c) { this.mContext = c;}

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String returnMessage() {
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "This is being called from the interface", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return "This is being called from the interface";
    }
}
```

At this point any time we want to access the code for the `returnMessage()` method inside of the webview we simply call:

```
var getContentsFromIntefrace = Android.returnMessage()
// getcontentsFromInterface is now "This is being called from the interface"
```

These targeted calls(`Android.returnMessage()`) allow me to call the interface code only when I need to do so, in contrast, if I was to use Android API´s evaluate javascript methods I would have to watch for the code executing all over the place e.g if my evaluatejavascript Android API method sets a variable to something it will do so in any other part of the code where said variable exist(please do correct me if I am wrong, it seems fuzzy at first but it is an issue thus far)

===== The issue I am having with IOS

The above is merely an explanation of what I need to do, to show what I am attempting on IOS I will demonstrate the code:

In IOS if I want to se functions that call on swift code inside my controller I have to set it in JS as:

```
function testButton() {
    webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandlerTestSend.postMessage({action: "testButtonAction", data: {name: "E.A.P"}});
}
```

The above sends a named message('callbackHandlerTestSend') with the key value pairs of action and data which can be parsed on the appropriate swift delegate as:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if (message.name == "callbackHandlerTestSend") {
            guard let body  = message.body as? [String:Any] else {
                print("Unable to do connection")
                return
            }
            for(key, value) in body {
                print("\(key) : \(value)")
                if(key == "action"){
                    if(value as! String == "testButtonAction") {
                        intCounter += 1
                        print("The testButtonAction message action has been called")
                        webView.evaluateJavaScript("receiverP.innerHTML = 'It works \(intCounter)'", completionHandler: nil)
                        webView.evaluateJavaScript("receiverFunction('Message test')", completionHandler: nil)
                        // FIXME:  evaluate JS might call on any other instance of receiverP, this is an issue
                    }
                }
            }

        }// body of if

    }// end of delegate
```

This is currently the only way in which I have been able to send Swift code back to the `webview`, by injecting the Javascript code with `webView.evaluateJavascript()`

My problem is that I need to capture everything with the whole:

```
webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandlerTestSend.postMessage({action: "testButtonAction", data: {name: "E.A.P"}});
```

And it becomes bothersome to continue to do it as well as to have to individually parse each call for the proper parameters to be set while at the same time trying to not inject javascript code without messing something else up. So calling javascript and sending javascript code seems extremely cumbersome at this point and I would like to know if there is something I could do for the code to look more like the Android counterpart.

Any advice on what cool external libs out there I could use or in how could I modify the code to this would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying to find something in the IOS docs but have not found anything that I could use.

-- Edit:

At this time I am seriously considering an alternative such as React Native since it seems as the fastest route to develop an application that requires heavy usage of web like content as well as having limited knowledge of IOS in contrast to Android. I would still want to know if there is a viable solution to the above.

Comment: Sadly I do not know of a different way to handle this.  Hopefully someone will be able to give you(and me) a answer.  I created a feature of a project using Fabric.js in a WKWebView and ended up with a switch statement checking the `message.name` with lots of 'branches'. If you have control over the files, like I did, I simply added in JS functions, and called them to return the data needed in `WkWebView.evaluateJavascript()`...just keep in mind that, that function, is async :) unlike UIWebView's evaluateJavascipt

Comment: @JacobBoyd thank you Jacob, it has been hard thus far, some of the functions that need to get called form the javascript take callbacks, which is proving really hard to do, i hope someone gets to give us a few pointers.